# Do people eat clotted cream AND butter at the same time?

Tags: butter, clotted-cream

In *The Hobbit*, Gandalf is described as eating loaves with clotted cream, butter, and honey.  I'm familiar with clotted cream, but I always eat it with jam - clotted cream PLUS butter seems excessive.  Do people frequently eat these things together?

Comment: I'm sure that **someone** does. I don't know that it's standard.

Comment: @Catija - that's more the question.

Comment: I am inclined to close this, as there is **no standard** in eating food. Or does someone see a way to provide an objective answer to this question?

Comment: @rumtscho Please do! I so agree with you - too broad and opinion based. What can we say beyond "some do, some don't". Many of us have their personal, regional or cultural quirks with regard to food....

Comment: It's hard to butter while you're eating clotted cream. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really a matter of preference. Some people like the salty dimension that butter gives along with clotted cream and jam, others think the cream is enough saturated fat to be going on with.